# Applying the SSL(Secured Socket Layer) security in Kafka stopped the broker server

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

After applying the SSL(Secured Socket Layer) in the Kafka broker-server it stopped working.

certificate are created and stored at respective directory.

[![The image show created certificate][1]][1]

Have put all the configuration in the server.properties file and restarted after the setting change but only zookeeper start,broker server didn't start.

```
listeners=SSL://xxx.xxx.com:9093

advertised.listeners=SSL://xxx.xxx.com:9093

ssl.truststore.location=/xx/xx/kafka.server.truststore.jks

ssl.truststore.password=xx

ssl.keystore.location=/xx/xx/kafka.server.keystore.jks

ssl.keystore.password=xx
ssl.key.password=xx
```

server log file-

```
INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

ERROR Invalid configuration, only one server specified (ignoring) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)

INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)

INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)

WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
```

kafka log file-

```
[2020-12-07 01:42:33,617] ERROR Fatal error during SupportedServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured listeners are SSL
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1795)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1770)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1346)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1326)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1323)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.<init>(SupportedServerStartable.java:61)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:45)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,182] INFO Reading configuration from: /u01/app/kafka/latest/etc/kafka/zookeeper1.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,188] INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,188] INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,192] ERROR Invalid configuration, only one server specified (ignoring) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,195] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,195] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,196] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)

[2020-12-07 00:56:15,196] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/
```

32RSy.png

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: check it i have added

Comment: That's Zookeeper logs, not Kafka

Comment: zookeeper.log file is not containing any data in it.
There is one more file zookeeper-gc.log0.current generated with it.

Comment: Again, you've said Zookeeper is starting fine. Kafka isn't. Please show the Kafka process logs

Comment: added the kafka log check it